# Why to downgrade Angular 2 application in order to use Angular 1 directive

Tags: angularjs, angular

We have developed many Angular 1 components and would like to use it in our Angular 2 application. But the documentation describes that we have to downgrade the Angular 2 application in order to upgrade and use the Angular 1 directive. Why is this? Here we are not upgrading NG1 app, but we want to use NG1 directives in NG2 application. Are there any downside of downgrading Angular 2 application like performance degradation.

Comment: Could you post a link as to where you found this information in the docs?

Answer (score 1):

As for as I know Angular 2 components are built with typescript where as angular 1 uses java script may be that's the reason we need to downgrade the angular 2 to angular 1 to use there corresponding directives

Please go through this [link](http://blog.rangle.io/upgrade-your-application-to-angular-2-with-ng-upgrade/) you may get some Idea